# To find out a previous row's calculated value in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

[a sql query gives result as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VayEn.jpg)

i want an extra calculated column which is populated by subtracting deduct from salary for serial no 1 and for other serial no salary would be previously calculated row which should used for current row salary deduct as shown in picture below

[populated result would be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CXDE.png)

please help me to find out result. thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012+, you would use a cumulative sum and subtraction:

```
select t.*,
       (salary - sum(deduct) over (partition by employee order by sn)) as calc
from t;
```

Comment: @Rahulpatel . . . If you are using SQL Server 2012, check your compatibility:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level.